# Get vertical scroll inside a div with fixed width using Css

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, vertical-scrolling

I have a fixed size div say 500px. It has a smaller div inside it.
when the number of divs increases It starts to give a horizontal scroll.
I want it to have a vertical scroll inside. I tried doing this:

```
width: 1509px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

this didn't work so i hope you guys can help me out.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share what you have done so far

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly have a look

Comment: that div has display set to flex . I think that is the issue. But I kind of need flex there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my mistake:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 265px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I was not setting flex-wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.container, .item {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='item'>1</span>
  <span class='item'>2</span>
  <span class='item'>3</span>
  <span class='item'>4</span>
  <span class='item'>5</span>
  <span class='item'>6</span>
  <span class='item'>7</span>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But not this.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you.

```css
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.child {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 This is content. This content needs bottom scroll. This is content. This content needs bottom scroll.
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to make sure that your child div's width should be more than parent div.

Comment: but I don't want a horizontal scroll

Comment: Do same thing with the height element and replace the css 
`    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: I have found the issue. I was not setting flex-wrap.